# Excel: how manipulate values based on selections in 2 drop downs

Tags: excel

Is it possible to have 1 table with data like this:

[image: Example excel table with dummy data]

And use it's data to create 2 drop downs, so that when both of "chars" get selected, there's a final value formed based on the "value" column, which correspond to each char? Like here:

[image: Example result table]

*Cells in yellow are drop downs (lists).*

Result 6 comes from 1 + 5. 1 is the "Value" of the "Char" A and 5 is the "Value" of the "Char" E.

**EDIT**

My real table has many more columns than in the example, so I would need to be able to pick a column when I need the data to be fed from for the final calculation.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Here is a pretty good tutorial for this: http://www.contextures.com/xldataval02.html

Comment: Thanks Dan, it's indeed a good start. However, my real source table has more than 6 columns, and I need to be able to pick a value from a N-th column for my final calculation.

Comment: So you don't necessarily want to use all of the columns? Can there be a default value for each column? The method in that tutorial should generalize for n cascading dependent lists...

Comment: Yes, Dan, thanks to the tutorial I was able to play around with different functions with quite a success. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a solution with four dropdowns -- two to choose Char values, and two to choose from which column to use a value (one for each Char).  Here's a sample using a table with more columns.

[image]

As @Dan indicated in the comments, you should create the dropdowns using list validation.  I don't see a need for the dropdowns to be cascading or interdependent, so this should be really straightforward.

The Result value can be calculated using `VLOOKUP`s with `MATCH` functions used to choose the column from which to return a value.

```
=VLOOKUP(A9,$A$2:$D$6,MATCH(C9,$A$1:$D$1,0),FALSE)+VLOOKUP(B9,$A$2:$D$6,MATCH(D9,$A$1:$D$1,0),FALSE)
```